# How to get values in controller from form data?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vue.js

In vue.js i have this:

```
  var data = new FormData();
    data.append('name',this.property_credentials.name);
    data.append('default_image',this.$els.fileIntroImage.files[0]);
```

When i do this i have values :

```
  console.log('default_image',data.get('default_image'));
```

But problem is when i try to get values in controller i get null:

```
 $intro_image = $request->input('default_image');
```

Any suggestion how can i get values in controller from form data?

EDIT:

```
this.$http.put('/profile/'+ user_id +'/property/'+ property_id +'/edit', data).then(function(response) {
                $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
                this.property_status = true;
                this.property_success_update_message = response.data.successUpdateMsg;
            } , function(response) {
                $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
                this.property_status = false;
                this.property_errors = response.data
            });
```

Comment: `dd($request->all())`; What's in there?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy any suggestion why is that happening?

Comment: How are you posting the data? Can you show the code that posts it?

Comment: @devk i edited my question

Comment: Globally, set `Vue.http.options.emulateJSON = true; Vue.http.options.emulateHTTP = true;` before you send the request.

Comment: https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource/blob/master/docs/config.md#legacy-web-servers